# Android Remote Services

Tags: android

I was looking at the commonwares example on remote android services. I keep getting this errors in logcat

```
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624): java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at com.commonsware.android.advservice.client.IScript$Stub$Proxy.executeScript(IScript.java:82)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at com.commonsware.android.advservice.client.RemoteClientNewActivity$2.onClick(RemoteClientNewActivity.java:59)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9277)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-22 19:50:33.947: E/AndroidRuntime(30624):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
```

I have been trying to resolve it for a while now.

In the activity this is what I do

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.commonsware.android.advservice.IScript");
    bindService(i,svcConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and

```
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder binder) {
        service=IScript.Stub.asInterface(binder);
        if(service !=null){
            message = "connected";
        } 
    }
```

Please can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, based on the error message, your AIDL is out of sync between the service and the client. They need to be using the same AIDL definition. "Binder invocation to an incorrect interface" suggests that your client has one version of the AIDL and your service is using a different one.

Comment: I figured along those lines but they are 2 separate projects and the only way i know to grant access to the client from the service is a simple import statement and also declaring in the manifest of the service class the full package name of the .aidl file. Still stumped

Comment: @Arkangel: "the only way i know to grant access to the client from the service is a simple import statement" -- I have no idea what you are talking about. "also declaring in the manifest of the service class the full package name of the .aidl file" -- the AIDL file has nothing to do with the manifest. The use of AIDL is covered [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html), not to mention [the book that is the home for the sample code you are trying](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid).

Comment: Fixed the problem today...copied the package tht holds the .aidl in the service to the client, created a separate package for the client activity and it works. Mistake was binding to a .aidl interface based on the client package name NOT the service package name.

Comment: That documentation gives a 404 now, book still works obviously!

Comment: @Knossos: That URL does not 404, at least when I try it. Regardless, the book content was merged into this other book: http://commonsware.com/Android/

Comment: Documentation has not specified it clearly,that .aidl in client should have same package as Remote .aidl

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I got this error because I had another variant of this service installed on my device, once I removed it, everything was good.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

I had the same issue and according to my research (like 4 hours) do the following:

Let me say you have an **Activity A**, that is holding the service itself and an **Activity B** , that wants to access the Service of Activity A.

**Make sure that both Apps (A & B) use the same package name (e.g. com.example.coolname). Especially that one containing the AIDL-File.** *Seems to be very important.*

Before I did this I always got the `java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface` when I tried to work with the return IBinder object. (bindung itself worked well)

Answer (score 0):

copied the package tht holds the .aidl in the service to the client, created a separate package for the client activity and it works. Mistake was binding to a .aidl interface based on the client package name NOT the service package name

Answer (score 0):

The .aidl file at the client side must live under the same package name that hosts the service you are calling. In order to do that create a new package at the client side with same name as the package of the application hosting the service. You can do this by **right-clicking on the src folder of client** and choosing **new->package**. After that, **copy the .aidle file under that new package**. I was getting this error since I was placing my .aidl under my client package. Doing this package fixing solved my problem. I think the Android manual page for AIDL fails to communicate it clearly to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the same AIDL file in the client side under the same directory as it is there in server side.
So please copy the AIDL file path directory from the server and paste it in your client side.

Foe example, suppose in the server you have the .aidl file at the below path :-

`com.theD.aidlExample` ->in this path you have `MyAIDL.aidl`

now go to your clients src directory and make the same directory structure in the src directory of client, i.e `com.theD.aidExample`  and place the server's aidl file i.e `MyAIDL.aidl` in the client side newly created directory path